# How to locate element by both id and attribute at the same time in js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Now I have a html tag:

```
<textarea class="form-control" comment_id={{comment_id}} id="reply_content" style="height:100%;" placeholder="comment here">This is the content</textarea>
```

How can I get the value of the html value here? I mean the string:" This is the content  "

I tried:

```
  var pid= $(this).attr("comment_id");
  var content =$(`textarea#reply_content[comment_id="${comment_id}"]` ).val();
  console.log(content);
```

But not work.Any friends can help?

Comment: An id should be unique, just getting it by id should be sufficient.

Comment: You don't set `comment_id`, you set `pid`, so the variable name is wrong. However the above is correct, `id` ***have*** to be unique so using a tagname and attribute selector along with the id is entirely redundant. If you have multiple textarea with the same id, then that's an issue you'll need to fix. I'd also suggest you remove the non-standard `comment_id` attribute, or change it to a `data` attribute instead.

Comment: Code is incomplete. You defined pid, you use a variable comment_id.....Seems like you have a bug with wrong variable usage, but hard to tell since it is 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

At the line of textarea, are you sure your variable {{comment_id}} does not need quote before and after it? Just questioning?

```
<textarea class="form-control" comment_id={{comment_id}} id="reply_content" style="height:100%;" placeholder="comment here">This is the content</textarea>
```

And to select it, you were on good path, you had to do just this:

```
var pid= $(this).attr("comment_id");
var content =$('textarea#reply_content[comment_id="'+pid+'"]').val();
```

And it should work, as you got id in variable pid before.

And also if you have multiple `#reply_content`, you should change it to class instead of id, as there should be only one id per page!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue my fault I used a wrong name.